# <div> section to be trigger of show/hide content by click html/css only

Tags: html, css

:)
I started making a website few days ago and I'm stuck at this step:
http://jsfiddle.net/r6uhczks/

**CSS:**

```
  /* This section to be trigger of dropdown process */
.parent_style { background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0.5),transparent); width: 325px; height: 21px; }
.parent_style:hover { background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(242,182,0,0.7),transparent); }
.parent_style .textP {}
.parent_style:hover .textP {color: red;}

/* This section to be shown by clicking on ↑ and hidden by clicking for second time */
.child_style { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); width: 325px; height; auto; }
.child_style:hover { background: rgba(242,182,0,0.7);}
.child_style .textC {color: white;}
.child_style:hover .textC {color: black;}
```

As you can see I created two styles for dropdown menu,

> .parent_style

defines trigger of show/hide content defined by

> .child_style

Simplier I want to make a **class="parent_style"** to be show/hide trigger of shown/hidden **class="child_style"**
The problem is that I don't know how to create this action by click with CSS/HTML only, I know only by hover.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent_style">
    <p class="textP">Something</p>
</div>
<div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content</p>
</div>
    <div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content2</p>
</div>
    <div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content3</p>
</div>
<div class="parent_style">
    <p class="textP">Something else</p>
</div>
<div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content</p>
</div>
    <div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content2</p>
</div>
    <div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content3</p>
</div>
<div class="parent_style">
    <p class="textP">Something else 2</p>
</div>
<div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content</p>
</div>
    <div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content2</p>
</div>
    <div class="child_style">
    <p class="textC">Content3</p>
</div>
<br>
```

EDIT: and also I would like to know how to edit spaces between these elements, best to remove them.

Comment: It is impossible to have an onclick trigger with just css and html. You will need to include javascript or jquery.

Comment: I'm affraid that host of my website don't allow me to use custom js. :/ 
but I can try. Can you post solution using js?

Comment: something like this? http://htmlbank.net/?FK

Comment: Are you allowed to redo any of the HTML, such as nesting the child_style divs inside of the parent_style divs? If you can I have a solution with JQuery that'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use custom html and css, i'm sure you can stick a custom script at the bottom of the page if it doesn't allow you to add to the head (keep in mind this script requires the page to be loaded first).

Because the elements are not paired together in individual divs, the javascript is a bit longer but nothing too complicated. This script I created will scan through all the divs on the page and will allow the onclick function to determine what the next three divs are. This means that the script is custom to your layout of navigation so you'll need to change the javascript with a layout change.

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLc4svam/

```
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");   
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("parent_style");
for (var i=0; i<parents.length; i++) {
    parents[i].onclick = function() { toggleChildren(this); };
}
function toggleChildren(elem) {
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length;i++) {
        if (divs[i] == elem) {
            for (var ii=1; ii<=3; ii++) { // The 3 is how many children it will toggle
                if (divs[i+ii].style.display == "none") {
                    divs[i+ii].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    divs[i+ii].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. This one is awesome.
But I have one more question, is there a way to set hidden as default?

Comment: @t4dohx Yes, you set this in the css of the child. `display:none;` or the full line `.child_style { display: none; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); width: 325px; height: auto; }`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I wanted :)
*solved*

Comment: Hmm, sorry for annoying but is there a way to keep .parent_style hovered when hovering child_style?

Answer (score 1):

You can add state to CSS and HTML by using checkboxes (persistent) or focus (temporary):

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/L40zcjfc/

HTML

```
<button>hold down here</button>
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ul>

<br />
<br />

<button><label for="cb1">click here</label></button>
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" />
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
input,
ul {
    display: none;
}

button:active + ul,
input:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The persistence comes from the checkbox's `:checked` state. You can toggle the checkbox with a `<label>` so you don't have to know it's there.

The temporariness comes from the `:active` state of a button. Maybe you can use a normal link, but that might keep focus and/or active.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
But this one doesn't work in my website, I don't know why. 
Using webnode.

Comment: One up because this is great new code for me, but it seems to not work in IE because of the use of a button for purposes other than a function. It does work when I change the button to a span but then it doesn't work for ie8 and below.

Comment: Dude, IE 8 and below? =) Yeah, it doesn't work everywhere. I only tested Chrome. There might be better variants. It's a cool concept though IMO.

Comment: I don't know why but this solution doesn't work for me. (using latest version of Chrome).
It working fine in jsfiddle but not in my website :/

Comment: Make sure the elements are in the right order and tree. The button must be before and next to the element you want to show/hide, and not inside a container. The CSS relies on `+` or `~`, which are **sibling** selectors.